# Application's new version uploaded on iTune with internal testing enabled not appearing on Testflight app

Tags: ios8, xcode6, app-store-connect, testflight

I have released one version on my Application on iTune and is in process to release second one. Now I have uploaded the the .ipa file of the application and switching on for internal testing. But the application is not appearing on Testflight app of internal tester. I am uploading the .ipa file through Xcode 6.1 and also trying with Xcode 6.3.

Comment: This question is unlikely to garner good answers as it is off topic as discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293610/916299)

Comment: No issue @JamesWebster I will asking on Apple Development forum.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the app on iTunes, then you can not add new IPA in existing version of app.

Comment: This isn't true since iTunesConnect was updated a few months ago. You can have several builds for the same version of an app

Comment: Yes, but before submitting app to iTunes.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? The OP has already uploaded new versions. The question talks about Internal Testing via Test Flight

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that for your app you have turned the switch ON for TestFlight Beta Testing.

[image: Check the snapshot from my iTunes Connect account]

Once done with that go to Internal Testers tab and check the internal testers from the list and invite them. Thats it! Hope it helps :]

Cheers!

Comment: @Chanda005 the switch is ON.

Comment: @ShrinivasKulkarni Have you added internal testers for the app from the list of Internal testers in Internal Testers tab?

Comment: I have added the internal testers for the App and also invited those user.

Answer (score 0):

If you've uploaded a build for the next/new version, you should see it at the top of the list of builds under the "Prerelease" menu for your app.

Assuming you're Build is in the list, check the "Internal" column for that build. If it says "Invite Testers", then that build is not yet active. What you probably need to do then is click the build number and make sure all the fields are filled out - especially "What to Test" - and then click the Save button. When you go back to the Builds list, it should now say "Active (30 Days Left)" under Internal. And should show up for testers in the TestFlight app.

I've noticed that sometimes I need to go through this process for a new build (even on a version I've already been testing) and sometimes I don't. I haven't found the pattern but it's tripped me up several times.